# AngularJS access loop length outside of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I basically want to hide the header if there are no items in the loop:

```
<div class="header" ng-if="notifications.length">
    <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in notifications" ng-if="!item.read">Stuff</div>
```

Is it possible to do this inside the template?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most elegant way, but if you actually need it to be done inside template, you can use `filter`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

In your case it would be something like:

```html
<div class="header" ng-if="(notifications | filter:read=false).length">
    <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
```

Also, you can use filter in `ng-repeat`:

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in notifications | filter:read=false">Stuff</div>
```

Also, you can define new array inside template, in parent of those div's. This will be probably most readable solution.

```html
<div ng-init="unreadNotifications = (notifications | filter:read=false)">
    <div class="header" ng-if="unreadNotifications.length">
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in unreadNotifications">Stuff</div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you use this inside the tempate

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="notifications.length">
  <div class="header">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
  ....
</ng-template>
```